# Vert.x how to deal with missing handler

Tags: memory-leaks, vert.x

Originally asked on the forum here - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vertx/jdNRWlE6v4Y

I just read [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/vertx/no%2420handler/vertx/jg6wq3aWMjc/q_v43iq4tu8J) discussing problems with sending out messages over the event bus where there is no registered handler for the specified address.
I'm just curious how folks deal with this scenario. Is a manual timer the recommended approach? Does this approach leak memory over time?

Coming from node I've seen a few approaches to this kind of problem:

1. Immediately throw an exception if the handler is not found
2. Callback with an error to clear the response listener
3. Catchall handler where you can put some code to decide how to deal with unhandled requests yourself

I'm open to these or any other methods, I just want to be sure I'm going about this in the correct way.

There is an [issue](https://github.com/vert-x/vert.x/issues/349) open for this but I don't know if it is worth looking into a fix for the current stable version (v1.3) or if I should wait for v2.0 (I haven't seen any sort of timeline for v2.0 but there does seem to be a lot of activity in the git repo around it).

Any guidance would greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://vertx.io/core_manual_java.html#sending-messages) says literally:

> "If you send a message specifying a reply handler, and the reply never
>   comes, then, by default, you'll be left with a handler that never gets
>   unregistered."

Sounds awful default behaviour to me too, but fortunately since Vert.x 2.0 we have a way to send with timeout, which looks like the way to go 100% of the times.

Example:

```
eb.sendWithTimeout("test.address", "This is a message", 1000, new Handler<AsyncResult<Message<String>>>() {
    public void handle(AsyncResult<Message<String>> result) {
        if (result.succeeded()) {
            System.out.println("I received a reply " + message.body);
        } else {

            System.err.println("No reply was received before the 1 second timeout!");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but this question is over a year old :-) Also, the vert.x team has clearly stated that all questions should go directly to their google groups forum (where this was answered a long time ago).